# SharePoint Online Discussions: Creating SharePoint Designer Workflows for Content types - Discussion and Message

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-designer, designer-workflow

I'm attempting to create a workflow for replies to discussions posted. What I am trying to achieve is getting the subject from the original discussion post (Content-Type: Discussion) to display in the workflow email set for replies (Content-Type: Message).

**Issue**: When the workflow to send out the notification for the reply is sent, the subject is blank. From what I have read, could be because the original entry is saved in the Discussion: Content-Type and the replies are being saved in the Message: Content-Type. The subject is being lost.

I have tried the following:

- Creating a variable and setting it to Subject, then calling the variable
- Using  Current Type: Subject

SharePoint Designer View:
[image]

My Result: (Subject comes out blank)
[image]

Comment: What's your issue?

Comment: Issue: When the workflow to send out the notification for the reply is sent, the subject is blank. From what I have read, could be because the original entry is saved in the Discussion: Content-Type and the replies are being saved in the Message: Content-Type. The subject is being lost.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using **Discussion Subject** instead of Subject

[image]